# How to append <script> to Head or Body Using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript problem.

I searched on google how to append  using javascript and I found an example. I want to manually append a `script` tag to head or body, but the example just appends in the head.

I edited the example so that the script tag can be appended in the head or body, but the code doesn't work.

Can anyone help me fix my problem? And please show me the demo on jsfiddle :D

Thanks :)

Here my script:

```
//JS
//Defined with  loadjscssfile("yourcssurl.js", "js", "head"); or addCss("yourcssurl.js", "js", "body");
//CSS
//Defined with  loadjscssfile("yourcssurl.css", "css", "head"); or addCss("yourcssurl.css", "css", "body");
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype, pos) {
    if (filetype == "js") { //if filename is a external JavaScript file
        var fileref = document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
    }
    else if (filetype == "css") { //if filename is an external CSS file
        var fileref = document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    }

    if (typeof fileref == filetype) {
        document.getElementsByTagName(pos)[0].appendChild(fileref)
    }

    else if (typeof fileref != "undefined") {
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
    }
}

loadjscssfile("myscript.js", "js", "body") //dynamically load and add this .js file
loadjscssfile("javascript.php", "js", "body") //dynamically load "javascript.php" as a JavaScript file
loadjscssfile("mystyle.css", "css", "body") ////dynamically load and add this .css file
```

And here is the original script, before I edited: [Dynamically loading an external JavaScript or CSS file](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml)

Sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close, but you don't need the extra `if` condition you added, this should be sufficient:

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype, pos) {
    var fileref;

    if (filetype === "js") { //if filename is a external JavaScript file
        fileref = document.createElement("script");
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
    }
    else if (filetype === "css") { //if filename is an external CSS file
        fileref = document.createElement("link");
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename);
    }

    if (fileref) {
        document.getElementsByTagName(pos)[0].appendChild(fileref);
    }
}
```

Give that a shot.

Comment: thanks! you're good man :D Your code is working as what I want. :D > the demo http://jsfiddle.net/bagusa4/vg7ysa8o/ hii :D

Answer (score 4):

You can learn from google to appending scripts dynamically

```
(function () {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve at the end of the day, but take a good look at the script, it's async. So you do not worry about the sequence of the resource loading.

In some use cases, you might need to control the sequence of the script loading, you can consider using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/)